# k-d tree with rectangles

Tags: java, kdtree

I've got my implementation of a k-d tree working with given points. For example, I can add points to the tree and then find the nearest point to given x, y coordinates, which is great.

I want to extend this to work with rectangles, for example a user gives an x and a y coordinate, a width and a height, I then want to be able to do a range query and nearest neighbour searches on this structure. How would I go about extending the current tree that I had to work with rectangular data?

Answer (score 2):

K-d trees are great for low dimensional point data. For anything consisting out of multiple points (lines, rectangles, etc) I would suggest using an R-tree.

Answer (score 2):

I know a great extension of k-d trees to handle rectangles. It is called *Box Sort* algorithm and can be found here [Box sort](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01952830?LI=true).
The idea is pretty much the same as k-d trees. The paper has also an implementation in Pascal, but the translation to Java should be straightforward.